# MongoDb InsertManyAsync Method Just Add First Document

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0

I have a method and I need multiple insert into mongodb. But, this code working for the first item of values list. It has 3 items. How can I insert all of these three items.

```
public static async Task<List<Entity>> InsertEntities(List<Entity> values)
{
     string connectionString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";
     MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
     IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("OOSM");
     var collection = db.GetCollection<Entity>("Entities");
     await collection.InsertManyAsync(values);

     return values;
}
```

Comment: I found some explanation in log file but it is useless. I created user for admin and another user. Changed connection string mongodb://serkan:*********@127.0.0.1:27017  . But still same.  2015-05-26T17:03:51.604+0300 I ACCESS   [conn2090] Failed to authenticate admin@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user admin@admin
2015-05-26T17:03:51.605+0300 I NETWORK  [conn2090] end connection 127.0.0.1:10742 (2 connections now open)

Comment: I have solved the credentials problem but still it couldn't write more than one document.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: No I couldn't solve the issue. I have changed the environment.

Comment: My apologies for not seeing the question sooner. We use InsertManyAsync constantly in all our tests, so it certainly works.